# Почему возникает ошибка Getting unknown property: common\models\LoginForm::secenario?

Tags: yii2

На локальном сервере ошибки нет, но на хостинге появляется ошибка

> Getting unknown property: common\models\LoginForm::secenario

не подскажите почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что нет свойства **secenario**. Поправьте в моделях на scenario